# How to use sed or awk to obtain just a directory

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

```
3:ââsdb1        8:17   1   984M  0 part /media/(NAMEOFDRIVEHERE)
```

I want to just have the `/media/(NAMEOFDRIVEHERE)` location so I can store it in a variable.

I've tried some `sed` commands and have had no luck. Any help or insight is appreciated.

Comment: What is that string? Output of a command?

Comment: Yes its the output of lsblk that i've tried to narrow down. this is the original output from lsblk:                                                                        NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb           8:16   1   984M  0 disk
ââsdb1        8:17   1   984M  0 part /media/KINGSTON
mmcblk0     179:0    0  14.5G  0 disk
ââmmcblk0p1 179:1    0 814.3M  0 part
ââmmcblk0p2 179:2    0     1K  0 part
ââmmcblk0p3 179:3    0    32M  0 part /media/SETTINGS
ââmmcblk0p5 179:5    0    60M  0 part /boot
ââmmcblk0p6 179:6    0  13.6G  0 part /

Comment: `lsblk | awk '/media/ {print $NF}'`

Comment: YES! Thank you! I needed to get specifically the name of the media device so i could store it into a variable, settings was still printing but i just cut out /media/SETTINGS. You're awesome jasonwryan

Comment: `lsblk` can do it on its own: `lsblk -nlo mountpoint /dev/sdb2`

Comment: `findmnt -noTARGET /mount/point` or use -so to search against the SOURCE device. `findmnt` won't print any mount not rooted at its argument path - and nothing at all if its queried path/device can't be found in the mount table - but use `-f` for none beneath it. Most usefully, `findmnt`'s return is testable, so `findmnt /mnt/point || mount ...` does what it looks like, and you can `--poll` mtab asynchronously to watch for changes in the mount table.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/media/{s#[^/]*/#/#;p;}'
```

or `awk`:

```
awk '/media/{print $NF}'
```

or using [lsblk](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsblk) itself:

```
lsblk -nlo mountpoint | grep 'media'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `grep`:

```
grep -o -E '(/.*)$'
```

Comment: Just use `grep -o '/.*$'`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use awk. It's good for such tasks as selecting data based on columns:

```
echo '3:ââsdb1  8:17  1  984M  0 part /media/(NAMEOFDRIVEHERE)' | awk '{print $7}'
```